# "No tests found" message on console on having tests file in the directory

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I am facing issue with configuration of playwright. Test scenarios is placed under the project directory but during execution it shows no tests found

1. npm i -D @playwright/test
2. npx playwright install
3. Execution : npx playwright test[image: Screenshot attached]

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you to solve your problem? If so, please mark it as correct to help others.

Answer (score 4):

You need to rename the filename to the `first.test.js` or add the `testMatch` property in the configuration file.

`testMatch` - Glob patterns or regular expressions that match test files.

Because by default, Playwright Test runs `.(test|spec)`

Comment: saved hours of my time..

Answer (score 0):

You may further choose a specific test in a file as well simply by:

```
npx playwright test -- grep "basic test"
```

Answer (score -1):

According to playwright.dev/js you should try naming your files "name.spec.js" or "name.spec.ts". https://playwright.dev/docs/intro

Alternatively, you can check your config to make sure that your test command is running files in the correct folder. This would be located in your playwright.config.js or playwright.config.ts file. Its name would be `testDir: 'folderName',`

If you dont have a config you can create it in the parent folder with the name of playwright.config.ts or js. Then paste the sample codes they give you on their dev site. https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#global-configuration